# Control flow with colum name in Julia dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am looking for a solution to handle with when column name is not exist in Julia dataframes.

In more detail, let's say I have following dataframes and list :

```
df = DataFrame(id= "12345", description= rand(5));
err_Li = ["12345"]
```

I need to check whether `id` column is match with `err_Li` such as :

```
if (df[1,"id"] in err_Li)
    println("NOT VALID")
else 
end
```

However, in some of my dataframes, column name `id` is not exist. So that in Python, I can handle with `try-except` such as :

```
try :
    if df['id'][0] in err_Li:
        print('err')
    else: pass

except : pass
```

How can I do control flow when column name is not exist in Julia dataframe or is there equivalent function with `try-except` in Python ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you know and expect that some of your dataframes will not contain this column, it is generally better to use ordinary control flow (`if`-`else`) in this scenario. Exceptions should be reserved for exceptional situations.

In this case, you can add an extra condition to your `if` statement, like this:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(id= "12345", description= rand(5));

julia> if columnindex(df, :id) > 0 && df[1, :id] in err_Li
           println("NOT VALID")
       end
NOT VALID

julia> df2 = DataFrame(blah= "13579", description= rand(5));

julia> if columnindex(df2, :id) > 0 && df2[1, :id] in err_Li
           println("NOT VALID")
       end

julia>
```

`columnindex` is a function that takes a DataFrame and a Symbol (`:id`), and returns 0 if the Symbol doesn't correspond to a column name in the DataFrame. If `:id` did exist as a column in the DataFrame, `columnindex` would return the position of that column (starting from 1), so in that case the result will be greater than 0. Thus, we can use it to check whether the column exists in our DataFrame, and only continue with checking the value if the column exists.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the answer given above you can use the `hasproperty` test:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(id="12345", description=rand(5));

julia> propertynames(df)
2-element Vector{Symbol}:
 :id
 :description

julia> hasproperty(df, :id)
true

julia> hasproperty(df, "id")
true

julia> hasproperty(df, :x)
false

julia> hasproperty(df, "x")
false
```

The reason this works is that data frame objects support getting their columns using the `.` syntax (which calls `getproperty`):

```
julia> df.id
5-element Vector{String}:
 "12345"
 "12345"
 "12345"
 "12345"
 "12345"

julia> df."id"
5-element Vector{String}:
 "12345"
 "12345"
 "12345"
 "12345"
 "12345"
```